# O que é Backlog?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos, scrum

Estava [lendo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlog) a respeito do termo **Backlog**, porem não entendi muito bem o que ele seria em relação ao Scrum. Pois, segundo este [site](http://www.desenvolvimentoagil.com.br/scrum/product_backlog), existe algumas variações de Backlog, e me pareceu estar associado ao Scrum. Essas variações seriam *Product Backlog* e *Sprint Backlog*, e isso me deixou mais confuso ainda a respeito de Backlog.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é Backlog em relação ao Scrum?
2. O que é Product Backlog?
3. O que é Sprint Backlog?
4. Qual é a influencia do Backlog em relação a um projeto em que esteja
   utilizando o Scrum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O que é Backlog em relação ao Scrum?

Backlog é uma lista do que tem que ser feito. Estou me referindo a definição sem relacionar com Scrum.

> O que é Product Backlog?

**Product Backlog** é uma lista de itens a serem feitos para construir um produto. Essa lista é mantida pelo **Product Owner** e é base para priorizar os planejamentos das iterações, ou **sprints**.

> O que é Sprint Backlog?

Uma vez que itens do **Product Backlog** são priorizados, o **Sprint Backlog** é gerado e então a equipe deve focar nesses requisitos durante essa iteração.

> Qual é a influencia do Backlog em relação a um projeto em que esteja
>   utilizando o Scrum?

O Backlog influencia o fluxo de atividades e prioridades que a equipe deve atender visto que tal deve ser alinhado as necessidades do cliente, em todas as sprints.